# DynamicsAX Webservice returns strange string

Tags: c#, web-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to extract SQL-Statements from dynamicsAx.

I followed this tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg844225.aspx

I then updated my getEmployee method to the following:

```
[SysEntryPointAttribute(true)]
public AA_PS_TableExchange getEmployee(int id)
{
    AA_PS_TableExchange xchange;
    Common buffer;
    ;
    buffer = SysDictTable::newTableId(id).makeRecord();
    select generateOnly buffer;
    xchange = new AA_PS_TableExchange();
    xchange.sql(buffer.getSQLStatement());
    return xchange;

}
```

My AA_PS_TableExchange looks like this:

```
[DataContractAttribute]
public class AA_PS_TableExchange
{
    int tableId;
    str sql;
}
[DataMemberAttribute]
public str sql(str _sql = sql)
{
    sql = _sql;
    return sql;
}
[DataMemberAttribute]
public int tableId(int _tableId = tableId)
{
    tableId = _tableId;
    return tableId;
}
```

Now, if i call the webservice from my c# code, it will always set the sql to "1" instead of the real sql statement. If i change this line:

```
  xchange.sql(buffer.getSQLStatement());
```

to

```
  xchange.sql("an assignment");
```

it works and i´ll get "an assignment" in my .Net code.

Any ideas what i am missing here?
I thought about it has maybe something to do with references but i got no clue here.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What table Id are passing in?

Comment: I tried it with 41, which is CompanyInfo.
Adding an info(buffer.getSQLStatement()); shows me the right statement, but it seems to not be stored via xchange.sql(...);

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem could only be in a few places:

Is `xchange.sql(...)` just accepting a base **AX** string type?

Have you performed an incremental CIL build?

Does `id` have a valid table id?

Try changing your code to this and do an incremental CIL build.

```
[SysEntryPointAttribute(true)]
public AA_PS_TableExchange getEmployee(int id)
{
    AA_PS_TableExchange xchange;
    Common buffer;
    DictTable dictTable = new DictTable(id)
    ;

    if (!dictTable)
        throw error("Table not found");

    buffer = dictTable.makeRecord();

    select generateOnly buffer;
    xchange = new AA_PS_TableExchange();
    xchange.sql(buffer.getSQLStatement());
    return xchange;
}
```

Comment: hi
because of the declaration of xchange.sql(...), which is in my post, i´d cut out the suggestion with the base AX string tpye. My knowledge about the x++ type systems is low so... maybe there could be something.

ID is valid.

I´ll try the code-change tomorrow.

Comment: I meant is it accepting `System.String` which would probably need to be cast first, or AX's str type or something that extends that.

Comment: as far as i remember the docu, buffer.getSQLStatemet() returns AX's str type.
Because of the signature:
public str sql(str _sql = sql)
I´d assume this should work, but i´ll check on this tomorrow back at work!

Comment: That's the detail I was curious to hear and yes that should work.  The only thing you might consider is bounding the string by doing `str 50 _sql = sql` or using an ExtendedDataType.  I think you just need to do an incremental CIL build honestly but you should error check.

Comment: The generated sql is between 2k and 3k in length. So i tried str 4000 but didn't help.
Thanks for pointing out the CIL-Build to me, i didn't know this feature exists, but it didn't solve my problem ...
I´m out of ideas, also tried moving the code to another method and calling it. 
If i call the class from a job, i´ll get the expected result, but not via the webservice.

Comment: You might need to refresh the service. I think you just right click and hit refresh/regenerate.  This guide is similar http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg840400.aspx

Comment: Hi. i didn't try this, instead i wrote myself a service that populates me a table with the statements i needed.
Thanks for the help!